# First Character is not getting detected/printed using Jline 2.14 with java

Tags: java, jline2

```
        int readChar = cnslRdr.readCharacter();
        if ( readChar == 9){                
                if (cnslRdr.readCharacter() == 9 ){                                         
                    cnslRdr.println("Double tab presssed..");                       
                    continue;
                }               
        }
```

The above code when run in commandprompt is not detecting the first character typed. The above logic is used to detect Double Tab key press in Jline2.14 console Reader

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation for this method and it seems to have a different signature than the one you are using.

```
public final int readCharacter(char[] allowed){...}
```

I didn't see any other overloads. I don't have any experience with JLine, but it may be that you need to pass an argument like new char[]{'\t'} to allow it to detect that keystroke.

Source: http://jline.sourceforge.net/javadoc/jline/ConsoleReader.html